# Help me securely store and retrieve Social Security numbers

Tags: encryption, mysql, decryption, compliance, pii

I am on the very last functionality to implement before launching my app. I have the same requirements someone like Fanduel or Draftkings does. When my users cross the $600 threshold for prizes in the year, I need to store their ss number so I can generate and email them a 1099 tax form for the next year.

I would be the only person in the organization needing to access this information.

How would you encrypt and decrypt this information? Do you have any thorough resources for me to look at? The stack is Angular/Spring Boot/MySQL.

Comment: First, do you know the requirements to secure Social Security numbers?

Comment: Stack Exchange has a lot to give you advice already: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+secure+social+security+number+in+web+app

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are already a lot of posts on StackExchange to cover this general question.